# How to say something like "surround me/it in circle" in just one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example imagine if you standing in the middle of stonehenge and you want to say "The stones are surrounded me in circle." in "The stones _ me." format.
What should I filled in the blank?

Comment: And I thought that the "round" in surround already meant it was a circle.

Answer (score 3):

***[encircle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encircle)*** seems the obvious choice:

> 1 :to form a circle around : surround
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encircle)*</sub>

Comment: Too obvious for an answer on a website intended for linguists.